# Javascript Canvas Animation with requestAnimationFrame becomes faster by path change

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I have a Canvas animation where serveral litle objekt(with objekt i mean picture aso a img element)come from up to down.

After i make 2 themes for this animation(i mean that the objekt have different picture depending on theme) the animation becomes faster after every path change respectively theme change.

And i dont have any idea what can be the reason.If anyone can help me i would be very glad.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>index</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/liabary.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/CSS.css">
</head>

<body class="body2">
    <center class="font2"><h2>Cookie Clicker</h2></center>
  <canvas  id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid; width: 800px; height: 810px;">no support</canvas>

            <img onclick="AnimationGroßCookie(); myFunctionAdd()" onMousedown="AnimationKleinCookie()" id="cookie" src="../img/cookie.png"  alt="cookie">
            <p class="font2" id="p1"></p><p class="font2" id="p2">gesammelte cookies:</p>

            <div onclick="DoubleClicker()" class="font2" id="buyMenu">
                    <p id="DoubleClicker" style="font-size: 19px; margin-left:30px;">Double Clicker</p>
                    <p style="font-size: 19px; margin-left:55px; margin-top:-15px;">kosten 20</p>
            </div>


            <div onclick="GeheimesVideo(); " class="font2" id="buyMenu2">
                    <p>Super Geheimes Video</p> <!--wennn gekauft langsam größer werdenes video-->
                    <p>kosten: 10.000</p>
            </div>


            <div onclick="AddPerSecond()" class="font2" id="Platzhalter">
                    <p>Platzhalter: 1cookie per second</p>
                    <p>kosten: 100</p>
            </div>

            <div onclick="ThemeÄndern0(); ThemeÄndernPath();" class="font2" id="Theme1">
                    <p>Cookie Theme:ändern per click</p>
            </div>

            <div onclick="ThemeÄndern1(); ThemeÄndernPath();" class="font2" id="Theme2">
                    <p>Donut Theme:ändern per click</p>
            </div>

<script>
console.log("Start");
var counter = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); //ctx = contex
var img = new Image();
var add1 = 10;
var rAF;//raf = requestAnimationFrame
Theme = 0;

                canvas.width = canvas.scrollWidth;
                canvas.height = canvas.scrollHeight;


                img.onload = function() {
                   console.log("Loaded image");
                     if (rAF) cancelAnimationFrame(rAF); //cancel prev animation frame
                   Hallo();
                };

function ThemeÄndernPath() {
    var cookie = document.getElementById('cookie');
                if (Theme == 0) {
                        img.src="../img/cookie.png";
                        cookie.src="../img/cookie.png";
                } else {
                        img.src="../img/donut2.png";
                        cookie.src="../img/donut2.png";
                }

}

                ThemeÄndernPath();
                //var CookieClickSound = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 0);

                var cookieArrayBreite =[];
                cookieArrayBreite[0]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[1]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[2]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[3]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[4]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[5]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[6]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[7]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[8]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[9]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[10]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[11]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[12]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[13]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[14]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayBreite[15]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);

                var cookieArrayHöhe =[];
                cookieArrayHöhe[0]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[1]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[2]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[3]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[4]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[5]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[6]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[7]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[8]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[9]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[10]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[11]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[12]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[13]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[14]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[15]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);

                setTimeout(function() { cookieCanvas(); },3000); //dont work
                window.setInterval(myCallback, 13200);

                    function myCallback() {
                                cookieArrayBreite[0]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[1]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[2]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[3]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[4]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[5]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[6]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[7]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[8]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[9]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[10]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[11]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[12]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[13]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[14]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                                cookieArrayBreite[15]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);

             console.log(cookieArrayBreite);
}

window.setInterval(myCallback, 13200);

    function myCallback() {
                cookieArrayHöhe[0]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[1]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[2]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[3]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[4]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[5]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[6]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[7]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[8]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[9]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[10]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[11]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[12]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[13]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[14]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);
                cookieArrayHöhe[15]  =  Math.floor((Math.random() * 810) + 0);

console.log(cookieArrayHöhe);
}


                function Hallo() {

                   if (add1 == 800) {

                      add1 = 10; // need to reset add's value

                      console.log("resetet");

                      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                      ctx.beginPath();
                      ctx.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
                      ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
                      ctx.fill();

                            ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[0], cookieArrayHöhe[0] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[1], cookieArrayHöhe[1] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[2], cookieArrayHöhe[2] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[3], cookieArrayHöhe[3] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[4], cookieArrayHöhe[4] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[5], cookieArrayHöhe[5] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[6], cookieArrayHöhe[6] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[7], cookieArrayHöhe[7] + add1, 50, 50);
                            ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[8], cookieArrayHöhe[8] + add1, 50, 50);
                      ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[9], cookieArrayHöhe[9] + add1, 50, 50);
                            ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[10], cookieArrayHöhe[10] + add1, 50, 50);
                          ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[11], cookieArrayHöhe[11] + add1, 50, 50);
                          ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[12], cookieArrayHöhe[12] + add1, 50, 50);
                          ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[13], cookieArrayHöhe[13] + add1, 50, 50);



                   } else {
                      console.log("Animation begining");

                      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

                      ctx.beginPath();
                      ctx.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
                      ctx.fillStyle = "lightblue";
                      ctx.fill();

                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[0], cookieArrayHöhe[0] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[1], cookieArrayHöhe[1] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[2], cookieArrayHöhe[2] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[3], cookieArrayHöhe[3] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[4], cookieArrayHöhe[4] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[5], cookieArrayHöhe[5] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[6], cookieArrayHöhe[6] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[7], cookieArrayHöhe[7] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[8], cookieArrayHöhe[8] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[9], cookieArrayHöhe[9] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[10], cookieArrayHöhe[10] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[11], cookieArrayHöhe[11] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[12], cookieArrayHöhe[12] + add1, 50, 50);
                         ctx.drawImage(img, cookieArrayBreite[13], cookieArrayHöhe[13] + add1, 50, 50);

                      add1++;
                   }
                     rAF = requestAnimationFrame(Hallo);
                   requestAnimationFrame(Hallo);
                }
</script>
<audio controls autoplay id="AudioClick">
  <source src="" type="">
   Audio element is not supported by your browser
</audio>

</body>

</html>
```

And her the liabarys:

```
function ThemeÄndern1(){
        Theme = 1;
}

function ThemeÄndern0(){
        Theme = 0;
}
```

PS:pls forgive me gramatical errors in my text i am still Student :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the previous animation frame before initiating a new one.

To accomplish so, first, declare a global variable, for instance ...

```
var rAF;
```

then, assign the `requestAnimationFrame` to that variable ...

```
rAF = requestAnimationFrame(Hallo);
```

and finally, cancel previous animation frame before calling the `Hallo` function ...

```
img.onload = function() {
   console.log("Loaded image");
   if (rAF) cancelAnimationFrame(rAF); //cancel prev animation frame
   Hallo();
};
```

Comment: that doen´t work if i do this the script is so fast that my brower is crahing i edit the code.

Comment: remove `requestAnimationFrame(Hallo);` after `rAF = requestAnimationFrame(Hallo);`